# grub cannot load my newly installed kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I needed a minimally-configured Real Time kernel, I compiled a new kernel with menuconfig. Firstly I added the rt patch to the new kernel directory using patch, and then ran make menuconfig.
Then I added the bzImage find inside arch/x86/boot/bzImage and the System.map files to /boot.

After that I ran update-grub.

Here are the contents of my grub.cfg

The problem is the the new kernel cannot be loaded when grub prompts.

Comment: Where are the contents of my grub.cfg?

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of `bzImage` to vmlinuz-kernel-version (vmlinuz-3.2.6 or what have you).

Also, kernel (vmlinuz) versions must start with a number `vmlinux-[0-9]` , update-grub will otherwise throw an error `dpkg: error: version 'version-rt19' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit` (error message used with `vmilinuz-version-rt19`)

You probably also need to install the modules

```
sudo make modules_install
```

And you probably need to make an initrd (depending on your hardware), again change "3.2.6" to your kernel version

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 3.2.6
```

Then re-run update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```